# Problems loading Web Essentials 2013 - Cannot load CssVariableDeclaration

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

VS 2013 Update 2
Web Essentials 2013 for Update 2

When I open a web project I get an error message from VS telling me an exception has occurred. When I check the `ActivityLog.xml` file I see the following error, many times

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 
    Microsoft.Css.Extensions.CssVariableDeclaration 
    from assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions
```

The call stack ends at `MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Css.ColorTagger.GetColors(CssTree tree, SnapshotSpan span)`

Any one know how to get past this one?

I have tried reinstalling Web Essentials and repairing VS2013

Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce the same with [nightly build](http://vswebessentials.com/download#nightly)?

Comment: I just installed the nightly and it still failed. The project I am working with may well have some badly formed LESS and SASS in it so I will try commenting it all out and gradually adding it back in

Comment: Perhaps, you can try reinstalling/repairing Web Tools from [http://asp.net](http://www.asp.net/downloads). Incidentally, do you have `Microsoft.CSS.Core.dll` and `Microsoft.CSS.Editor.dll` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Editor`?

Comment: I have tried reinstalling web tools before. I am going to reinstall Visual Studio itself. FWIW new MVC project workied fine. Then I added a .LESS file (with some simmple LESS) then as I pressed Save (assume it then loads a compiler) it threw the error. Yes those files are present and dated 28/04/2014

Comment: I removed VS2012 from the machine and repaired VS2013 and now the LESS features on WE are working